# Why firestore query for loop not returning in order?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get video data from query below. Whenever I try to fetch data inside for loop order of video ids are mixed. For example, sometimes the id for fetched videos are like that: "Video A"; "Video B" and after sometimes it turns to this: "Video B"; "Video A". Because of that behavior my onclicklistener not working properly. Code provided below:

```
Query query = db.collection("Videos").whereEqualTo("publisherId", model.getUserId());

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->  {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (task.getResult() != null) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Video video = documentSnapshot.toObject(Video.class);

                    thumbUrl = video.getThumbUrl();
                    videoTitle = video.getVideoTitle();
                    videoUrl = video.getVideoUrl();
                    videoDesc = video.getVideoDesc();
                    videoId = video.getVideoId();
                    publisherId = video.getPublisherId();

                    videoIdArrayList.add(videoId);
                    videoUrlArrayList.add(videoUrl);

                    Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(videoIdArrayList));
                }

                if (task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                        db.collection("Users").document(model.getUserId()).get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                        if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                            final User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                            if (user != null) {
                                if (user.getUserImageUrl() == null) {
                                        holder.userProfileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                } else {
                                        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(user.getUserImageUrl())).into(holder.userProfileImage);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

                    Glide.with(context).load(thumbUrl).into(holder.videoImageView);
                    holder.videoTitle.setText(videoTitle);
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to order returned data inside firestore query for loop. Thanks in advance

Edit:

HomeFragment.java:

```
private void setUpVideoRV() {
        Query query = followingRef.orderBy("followDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FollowList> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FollowList>()
                .setQuery(query, FollowList.class)
                .build();

        userHomeVideoAdapter = new UserHomeVideoAdapter(options, getContext());

        LinearLayoutManager videoLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        videoRV.setLayoutManager(videoLM);
        videoRV.setAdapter(userHomeVideoAdapter);
        userHomeVideoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried researching it at all? The first result of the *order Firestone" search should give you everything you need.

Comment: @HenryTwist I did extensive research on this issue but couldn't find any answer regarding order of firestore query for loop. The thing is as you mentioned query returns the result I need but not in order and that is the main issue for me because it causes problems when I handle onclick inside onbindviewholder. If you have any suggestions please let me know

Comment: So `orderBy` isn't what you're looking for? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: @HenryTwist Actually orderBy makes sense but I tried to add orderBy before but it says that I can't order query by publisherId because it was used inside whereEqualTo function. On top of that when I setup my recyclerview inside HomeFragment (I will add it to my question) I query it using different model and by "followDate" so I don't think data will match in first place.

Comment: When ordering by `followDate`, did you get the desired results?

Comment: @AlexMamo Unfortunately no followDate orders FollowList data inside my adapter but I need to order VideoIds inside my for loop